# How to rotate a square in diagonal axis using GSAP?

Tags: css, css-transforms, gsap

Its quite easy to do a diagonal rotation in CSS.

```
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,1,0,180deg)
```

http://codepen.io/moorthyrweb/pen/jEayJL

But, using GSAP how can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution from GSAP forum which includes two elements in the game.

```
TweenMax.set(".gsap",{rotation:45});
TweenMax.set(".container2",{rotation:-45});
TweenMax.to(".container2",1.5,{rotationY:180,repeat:-1});
```

http://codepen.io/MAW/pen/bNYWbx

Still, curious to know the best possiblity